# python return value from calendar widget class

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there an easy way to return the user selected date value to another python script using [this](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/ttk-gsoc/samples/ttkcalendar.py) code for a python calendar widget? I've saved the calendar widget in its own file named CalendarWidget.py.  I have a main gui with a button that opens the calendar widget.

```
def callback():
    t=tk.Toplevel()
    t.title("Calendar")
    cal = CalendarWidget.Calendar(t, firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)
    cal.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    cal.selection
```

This is working fine.  Now I just want to utilize the date. With the instance of cal.selection, I have tried saving the date.  However, I am finding the cal.selection line is interpreted before the actual selection is saved.  Thus I get a value of None for the calendar widget date.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem by altering your implementation such that when your Toplevel instance is closed, that is when you return `cal.selection`, or by adding a button whose callback both returns `cal.selection` and destroys the widget.